# Passport.js - return partial user object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

So I'm using passport.js authentication and storing several subdocuments that are relevant to my User model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: ''
  },
  actions: [{
    title: String,
    step: Number,
    addIf: [String],
    added: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }]
});
```

I'm new to passport, but curious to know how I can configure it to provide only a part of this User Model during the log in process, akin to:

```
User.findOne({
  _id: id
}, '-actions', function(err, user) {
  // get user object
});
```

Where is the best place to add this middleware?

EDIT: attempted through `deserializeUser`. Any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({
      _id: id
    }, '-salt -password -actions', function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

Comment: This can be done during the Strategy setup. Post your passport strategies code.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure in `passport.deserializeUser` method.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findOne({_id: id}, {actions: 0}, function(err, user) {
    console.log(err);

    // output user
    console.log(user.toJSON());

    // get user object
    done(err, user);
   });
});
```

You could read about these methods in the [official doc](http://passportjs.org/docs#sessions)

Comment: I've tried using `deserializeUser` and didn't get the expected results. see code update

Comment: Could you clarify where need you provide only a part of user, in a view? At now your user's model should be available via `req.user` in your routes. Is it?

Comment: yes. It seems when I use `passport.deserializeUser` it doesn't supply the fields in `req.user` for the serverside logic. I was referring to when the user information gets passed to the client - tried configuring the same in the `LocalStrategy` and that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Could you show me your user's output as in my updated answer? And could you show me how do you pass user to a client?